# React Navigation pass props from BottomTabNavigator to StackNavigator

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

**Summary**

I'm trying to pass an object when navigating from one route to another using React Navigation.  I can't receive the object in the screen I navigate too because it's in a different navigation stack.  If anyone knows how to that would be great!

When I do `Profile: { screen:ProfileScreen }` in the BottomTabNavigator, I'm able to receive props in ProfileScreen, however when I do `Profile: { screen: ProfileStack }` I can't pass props.

It seems like I navigation.state.params is not getting passed from the BottomTabNavigation to the StackNavigator since I console logged props in the screen I'm navigating too.  Does anyone know how to do this?

***Code***

**Navigation Stacks**

```
const ProfileStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Default: {
      screen: ProfileScreen
    },
    Settings: {
      screen: SettingsScreen
    }
  },
  stackConfig
);

const BottomTabNav = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeScreen
    },
    Competitions: {
      screen: Competitions
    },
    Profile: {
      screen: ProfileStack
    },
  },
  {
    tabBarComponent: CustomTabNav,
    initialRouteName: "Home"
  }
);
```

**Starting screen (Home in BottomTabNav)**

```
const HomeScreen = () => {
  const { eSportsUsername } = useSelector(state => state.user.userData);
  console.log("eSportsUsernamebb", eSportsUsername); //This is defined 

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.topNavIcons}
          onPress={() =>
            NavigationService.navigate("Profile", { eSportsUsername })
          }
        >
          <Image
            style={styles.topNavIcons}
            source={require("~/assets/images/profile.png")}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>

    </View>
  );
};

export default HomeScreen;
```

**Screen Navigated too (Profile in ProfileStack)**

```
const ProfileScreen = props => {
  const eSportsUsername = useNavigationParam("eSportsUsername");
  console.log("props", props);
  console.log("testtest", eSportsUsername);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Header header={eSportsUsername} />
      <View style={styles.body}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.settingsTouch}
          onPress={() => NavigationService.navigate("Settings")}
        >
          <Image
            style={styles.settingsImage}
            source={require("../../assets/images/settingsIcon.png")}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
Profile: { screen: props => <ProfileStack {...props} whatEverPropsYouWant={} /> }
```